# Putting Variable in Jquery Selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just want to dynamically put in the index, which is calculating correctly, so I know the value of my variable isn't a problem, but it's not working:

My variable 'parentIndex' stores the index of the span I want to be selecting below. I have tested this variable and it returns the correct value.

$(".DropDownMenu span:eq("+parentIndex+")")

is this not the right way to put a variable into a jquery selector? all the examples i've found use this format, what am i missing?

(The entire function, for context:)

```
        $("span input:radio").click(function() {
        if (($(this).is(":checked")) == true) {
            var elem = $(this);
            var parent = $(this).parent();
            var aunts = parent.parent().children();
            var parentIndex = aunts.index(parent);
            var position = elem.position();
            var topValue = position.top;
            topValue = topValue - 9;
            $(".DropDownMenu").css({ "top": "-" + topValue + "px" });
            $(".DropDownMenu span").css("background-image", "none");
            parent.css({ "background": "#f3f1e7 url(assets/images/branding/DropDownArrow.gif) no-repeat right" });
            $(".DropDownMenu span:eq("+parentIndex+")").css({ "background": "#f3f1e7 url(assets/images/branding/DropDownArrow.gif) no-repeat right" });

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
$(".DropDownMenu span").eq(parentIndex)
```

You can find more details of this in the [docs here](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/eq).

However, yours should work the way it is, make sure you use FireBug to test this, and maybe try it with a less complex function just to test it's functionality.

---

It would be cool if JS had something like `sprintf` and you could do something like: `$(".DropDownMenu span:eq(%parentIndex)"`

But that is just wishful thinking.

Comment: it worked, it's not behaving the way i want, but that's my fault, my function is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Have you debugged and seen what type parentIndex is?

try doing this:

```
$('.DropDownMenu span:eq('+ parseInt(parentIndex) +')');
```

Comment: yeah i did; it actually was working all along, I forgot i needed to use the index to figure out nth child. I was just being stupid. :-/